# Why is this button not aligning properly with another one in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Guys I have a problem with my relativeLayout.

Basically it does not align the buttons one next to each other.

I have two piano Keys and I am using Java Code to align them next to each other in relativeLayout.

Here's the code

```
wk[0] = new Button(this);
wk[1] = new Button(this);
wk[0].setId(0);
wk[1].setId(1);
wkParams[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wkw,wkh);
wkParams[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wkw,wkh);

wkParams[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
wkParams[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
wkParams[1].addRule(RIGHT_OF,wk[0].getId());

relativeLayout.addView(wk[0],wkParams[0]);
relativeLayout.addView(wk[1],wkParams[1]);
```

I want the two buttons to be next to each other. Unfortunately all I get is  wk[1] on top of wk[0] and i am not able to see wk[0].

Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: your layout params are same for both linear layout

Comment: Thanks for replying can you explain further?

Comment: I got it ! Thanks for your reply. It helped me find the answer. The problem was in the ID, if I set the ID to 0 and then use that later on, it will give me trouble because 0 is used for something else in the addRule method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout params are same for both relative layouts!!

Try this

```
wkParams[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 wkParams[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

or

```
         wkParams[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          wkParams[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```